# Problem with $20$ integers less than $70$

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

> 20 pairwise distinct integers each less than 70 are taken and their
>   pairwise differences are taken(magnitude of the difference). Show that
>   there always exists 4 equal numbers.

I somehow found the range of the differences and tried to show that we get a minimum four equal numbers but it was not that easy. Another tough question in my school exam which I couldn't solve.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299091

Answer (score 3):

Let us mark these numbers as $n_{1}, n_{2}, ... n_{19}, n_{20}$, but so that $n_{1}  \lt n_{2}  \lt ... \lt n_{19} \lt n_{20}$. This is then valid:

$$(n_{20} - n_{19}) + (n_{19} - n_{18}) + ... + (n_{3} - n_{2}) + (n_{2} - n_{1}) = (n_{20} - n_{1}) \lt69$$

Let's say there are no 4 same differences among $(n_{i+1} - n_{i})$. Then minimal value for their sum would be $3 \times 1 + 3 \times 2 + 3 \times 3 + 3 \times 4 + 3 \times 5 + 3 \times 6 + 7 = 70$, and this would mean $70 \lt 69$.

This means at least four of $(n_{i+1} - n_{i})$ must be the same.

Comment: This is taken straight from PSS and in my opinion lacks some justification

Comment: Justification of what?? @Confuse

Comment: I was having a bit of a tough time figuring out why the minimal would be $3*1+3*2+...+3*6+7$ but I do understand after a bit of a thought. This is probably the cleanest way to solve and this problem is way popular beyond PSS so I take my comment back :).